# How to change alert dialog header divider color android

Tags: android, colors, dialog, styles, android-alertdialog

I wanted to style or change divider color of header title in alert dialog. I search about this question and I think lot of people searching for this.But I am still not able to find out right solution. I want to change this following.
[image: Blue header divider]

Comment: have you tried setDivider method? does it exist in alert dialogs?

Comment: I created costume dialog for my older android versions but for newer android version i want to change this blue divider color. for older version i fully create my custom dialog. But i don't want to use it for higher versions. So that's problem. Any way to change that.

Comment: if so ,you don't want to create custom dialog then you may have to change the theme , or else you have to use custom dialog box..

Comment: I tired it into them as well see I change color of header title. But I am not able to change that divider color. And I really don't want to use custom alert dialog for my higher version of android.

Comment: did you find solution?

Comment: This may help you:-

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14439538/how-can-i-change-the-color-of-alertdialog-title-and-the-color-of-the-line-under

Answer (score 16):

You can actually change color of AlertDialog title by a very simple hack:

```
public static void brandAlertDialog(AlertDialog dialog) {
    try {
        Resources resources = dialog.getContext().getResources();
        int color = resources.getColor(...); // your color here

        int alertTitleId = resources.getIdentifier("alertTitle", "id", "android");
        TextView alertTitle = (TextView) dialog.getWindow().getDecorView().findViewById(alertTitleId);
        alertTitle.setTextColor(color); // change title text color

        int titleDividerId = resources.getIdentifier("titleDivider", "id", "android");
        View titleDivider = dialog.getWindow().getDecorView().findViewById(titleDividerId);
        titleDivider.setBackgroundColor(color); // change divider color
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: Is this "future" safe?

Comment: The safest you can get I know

Comment: @Patrick can you please mention on which Android versions it doesn't work, e.g. below 15 on 17+ etc, so it will help others by no need to check for different versions

Answer (score 4):

Divider color:-

```
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
builder.setTitle(R.string.dialog)
   .setIcon(R.drawable.ic)
   .setMessage(R.string.dialog_msg);
Dialog d = builder.show();
int dividerId = d.getContext().getResources().getIdentifier("android:id/titleDivider", null, null);
View divider = d.findViewById(dividerId);
divider.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.my_color));
```

Comment: The key here is to run `.show()` first, and then access the dialog to get the divider View and make updates, etc.  I missed this at first - was trying to do the color update it before showing the dialog, and wasn't working.  Nice concise example - thanks

Answer (score 0):

I have found the easiest solution for updating colors to the alertBuilder's dialog divider.

There is no direct approach to achieve changing the color of the alert dialog divider. So, we can bypass the objects of the alert dialog using the ID of the default divider.

Usually, we will add alert.show() at end of the alertbuilders properties and function. Instead of alert.show() you need to replace the below set of lines to update the divider color for alert dialog.

```
 AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(SettingActivity.this);
            alert.setTitle("Delete");
            alert.setMessage("Are you sure want to delete ");
            alert.setPositiveButton("Delete", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

                   //Delete operations
                }
            });
            alert.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

                }
            });
            alert.setIcon(android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_alert);
            Dialog d = alert.show();
            int dividerId = d.getContext().getResources().getIdentifier("android:id/titleDivider", null, null);
            View divider = d.findViewById(dividerId);
            divider.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.blue_color));

        }
    });
```

**Important**: You should not use any other alert.show() at the bottom of the code. The alert will automatically take the show properties from the second line as mentioned above.

Answer (score -1):

Judging by the source, it seems that this color is hardcoded. I would consider this a bug, it should be styleable imho.

There is an easy workaround though : use `setStyle(DialogFragment.STYLE_NO_TITLE, R.style.myStyle);`, and write a simple linear layout where the first item is your title.

Comment: what are you applying setStyle to?  There is no such method for AlertDialogs (that I can see).  If this works I'd be happy to upvote your answer.

Comment: I use it in the onCreate of DialogFragment (and I advise you to use dialog fragments instead of fragments : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13765127/dialogfragment-advantages-over-alertdialog )

Answer (score -3):

```
QustomDialogBuilder qustomDialogBuilder = new QustomDialogBuilder(context).
        setTitle("Set IP Address").
        setTitleColor("#FF00FF").
        setDividerColor("#FF00FF").
        setMessage("You are now entering the 10th dimension.").
qustomDialogBuilder.show();
```