# How to color the divider of the Alertdialog.builder in android?

Tags: android

I am using the AlertDialog.Builder class to builder the alert with the radio buttons and the cancel button and I want to change the color of the divider and the radio button color how to do this can any one please provide solution.I checked all the answer from the stackoverflow about this related question.
And one more **i am using the v7Appcomapact Library.My min sdk is 10 and maximum is 18.** I don't want to use the custom layout.

Comment: `v7Appcomapact` doesn't provide customization of `AlertDialogs` if you want to achieve `Material Dialogs` you can try this library https://github.com/afollestad/material-dialogs

Comment: My project lower version is 18 not the 21?Can i use that library.

Comment: yes for sure, you can use the above said library

Comment: Thanx...but i manage to change the color of divider...

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
public static void brandAlertDialog(AlertDialog dialog) {
try {
    Resources resources = dialog.getContext().getResources();
    int color = resources.getColor(...); // your color here

    int alertTitleId = resources.getIdentifier("alertTitle", "id", "android");
    TextView alertTitle = (TextView) dialog.getWindow().getDecorView().findViewById(alertTitleId);
    alertTitle.setTextColor(color); // change title text color

    int titleDividerId = resources.getIdentifier("titleDivider", "id", "android");
    View titleDivider = dialog.getWindow().getDecorView().findViewById(titleDividerId);
    titleDivider.setBackgroundColor(color); // change divider color
} catch (Exception ex) {
    ex.printStackTrace();
}}
```

already answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21401181/3442067)

Comment: I said i have seen all the answer from the stackoverflow before.The function u have give me its parameter is AlertDialog i want for the Alertdialog.builder. If i used the the AlertDialog.Builder in your function give me an error at the "getWindow()" the error is can't resolves the method 'getWindows()'.