# How to Remove Alert Dialog Line in Lollipop

Tags: android, android-alertdialog

How to remove alert dialog line in lollipop? I just use the default alert dialog code it works fine in lollipop but somes times the dialog shows the line at bottom of the dialog in lollipop devices.

```
AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
alertDialogBuilder.setTitle("App Name"); 
alertDialogBuilder.setIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher);                
alertDialogBuilder
        .setMessage("Do you want to close this app?")
        .setCancelable(false)
        .setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {

            }
        })
        .setNegativeButton("No", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                dialog.cancel();
            }
        });
AlertDialog alertDialog = alertDialogBuilder.create();
alertDialog.show();
```

[image]

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10978692/styling-titledivider-in-dialog

Comment: sometimes is showing the divider, sometimes not. What the situations in which it is showing?

Comment: at app exit i will shows the dialog, its a default dialog not an custom dialog

Comment: yes, i fixed it by using custom views